# Sparkle framework doesn't check for updates on startup

Tags: cocoa, sparkle

I am developing a Cocoa application, and using the [Sparkle framework](http://sparkle-project.org/) for updating. I need to check whether any new version is available at startup. I added the `SUCheckAtStartup` key to info.plist and updated its status as true, but still the application is not asking for update at startup. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6):

It seems that this option has been removed and replaced with `SUScheduledCheckInterval` and `SUEnableAutomaticChecks`.

Also note that Sparkle deliberately does not check on first startup (to avoid spoiling first-run impressions).